# How can I get this abstract class to send its output to a socket?

Tags: java

I'm experimenting with creating a socket application that sends some data from another application to a client. The code to access the data uses an abstract class.

```
SubscriptionAdapter listener = new SubscriptionAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void onSubscriptionData(SubscriptionData data) {
    for (AnyJson json : data.getMessages()) {
      System.out.println(json.toString());
    }
  }
};
```

The mechanics of SubscriptionAdapter() were a little weird to figure out. onSubscriptionData gets called over and over and the for loop will return 1 to many records. Here is some sample output:

```
Yup
Got message: {"type":"lightning","location":{"coords":{"lon":18.509391,"lat":38.7581},"polarity":0}}
Yup
Got message: {"type":"lightning","location":{"coords":{"lon":18.504115,"lat":38.765076},"polarity":0}}
Got message: {"type":"lightning","location":{"coords":{"lon":18.494549,"lat":38.778813},"polarity":0}}
```

"Yup" is a line of debug code I put in above the for loop to confirm how the class functions.

Below is the sample socket server I'm working with:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Server {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) //throws Exception
    {   
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("Hello  client!");
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

The goal is to get `System.out.println(json.toString());` to output to the socket connection. However, I've been running into scope issues.

1. I can't just put the code for the server inside onSubscriptionData because it will keep trying to create a new socket on a port that is already open.
2. I can't put the code OUTSIDE of the abstract class because then `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);` winds up being out of scope.

I've been at it for a few hours and at this point, I could use some suggestions.

Update as requested. Below is the full code:

```
import com.satori.rtm.*;
import com.satori.rtm.model.*;

public class SubscribeToWeatherChannel {
  static final String endpoint = [end point];
  static final String appkey = [app key];
  static final String channel = "full-weather";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final RtmClient client = new RtmClientBuilder(endpoint, appkey)
        .setListener(new RtmClientAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void onEnterConnected(RtmClient client) {
            System.out.println("Connected to Satori RTM!");
          }
        })
        .build();


    SubscriptionAdapter listener = new SubscriptionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscriptionData(SubscriptionData data) {
        for (AnyJson json : data.getMessages()) {
          System.out.println(json.toString());
        }
      }
    };

    client.createSubscription(channel, SubscriptionMode.SIMPLE, listener);

    client.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is it a requirement that you have to use `System.out.println` to print to the socket?  That seems to make things difficult unnecessarily.  Instead, how about having either `SubscriptionAdapter` or the class that defines `listener` have its own `PrintWriter`?  Apologies if I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but without seeing the complete code I have to do some guessing.

Comment: Don't create an anonymous instance of the abstract class. Create a proper class that extends `SubscriptionAdapter`, then you can pass it PrintWriters or any other things you need. At its core this is still a question of "how do I use one class/object instace in another class".

Comment: @ajb There is really not much more to show but I'll update the question with the full code. It imports a big honking SDK https://github.com/satori-com/satori-rtm-sdk-java. `System.out.println` is just how it currently written so you can see what you are getting. json.toString() is really what needs to be written out.

Comment: @Kayaman I didn't write that bit of code. It's a code sample that I'm trying to understand so I was loathed to change it. I can try your approach though. If I'm reading the socket code properly, I'd have to pass in socket so we'll see how that goes.

Comment: Well, you can pass a `Socket`, but that ties the class to socket communication. If you pass a `Writer`, that would make it far more versatile. Not that it makes much of a difference here, but for future design experience.

Comment: @Kayaman Yup that got it!

Answer (score 0):

Credit actually to Kayaman for the solution.

> Don't create an anonymous instance of the abstract class. Create a
>   proper class that extends SubscriptionAdapter, then you can pass it
>   PrintWriters or any other things you need.

```
import com.satori.rtm.*;
import com.satori.rtm.model.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SpecificSubscriptionAdapter extends SubscriptionAdapter {

     public static PrintWriter out;

     public SpecificSubscriptionAdapter(PrintWriter out){
         this.out = out;

     }

     @Override
     public void onSubscriptionData(SubscriptionData data) {
       for (AnyJson json : data.getMessages()) {
         out.println(json.toString());
       }
     }
}
```